# Is there a quantum interpretation according to which quantum tunnelling is impossible at certain level?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-interpretations, quantum-tunneling

Is there a quantum interpretation according to which quantum tunnelling becomes physically impossible at certain (macroscopic) level?

Comment: This might get more interesting and useful results as a question about experimentation, like "Under what circumstances can an empirical science differentiate between that which is vanishingly improbable and that which is factually impossible?"

Comment: If we re-phrase my question the way you offer.... What is your answer?

Answer (score 2):

Technically speaking quantum tunneling is possible at any scale. However, because of the number of particles in a macroscopic setting, the chance for quantum tunneling of the entire object is close enough to 0 that it appears to be impossible.

Comment: I see that. But my question was about "impossible" interpretation, not about "appears to be impossible" (non-zero possibility) interpretation.

Comment: "quantum tunneling is possible at any scale". That is a conjecture, not an undisputed, empirically proven statement.

Comment: The mathematics implies it is always possible. There is no QM explanation for it being impossible at a macroscopic scale.

Comment: Of course, there can not be MATHEMATICAL explanation for it being impossible at a macroscopic scale. Such explanation should be physical.  Also: There is no empirically confirmed  QM explanation for it being possible at a macroscopic scale.

Comment: There are a lot of absolute impossibilities when considering conservation laws that cannot be broken. There is no tunneling to a different energy level for example.